# html not appearing

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-block

Below code is working fine in product/media.phtml

```
$_saleLabelHelper = $this->helper('custom_catalog/salelabel')
echo $_saleLabelHelper->getSaleLabelHtml($_product);
```

But the same code is not working in my custom template.

Code in function getSaleLabelHtml

```
public function getSaleLabelHtml($product, $type = 'icon', $discountTypeApplied = null)
    {
        $html = '';

        if ($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
            $html = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('custom_catalog/product_salelabel')
                ->setDisplayType($type)
                ->setDiscountTypeApplied($discountTypeApplied)
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->toHtml();
        }

        return trim($html);
    }
```

Tried with redirect code in template file but still not working.

```
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('custom_catalog/product_salelabel')
                ->setDisplayType('icon')
                ->setProduct(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(14581))
                ->toHtml();
```

Comment: Try relpacing `$this->helper('custom_catalog/salelabel')` with `Mage::helper('custom_catalog/salelabel')` in your custom template

Comment: @AnilSuthar : Tried it as well, but not working.